# Why do we have to study history as an independent discipline rather than as a sub-field of other subjects?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-history

Would it not be better if a historical event were to be analyzed under the lens of a discipline that is most to related to it? Take, for example, the splitting of the atom. Surely, a physicist would be the best person to explain how profoundly such discovery influenced the 20th century science. A historian could definitely  share something valuable regarding the subject, but it would not be as in-depth as that of a scientist.

Comment: Can you unpack this a little further? Is there something specifically about the philosophy of history that you're reading or studying that made this an important or interesting question in your mind?

Comment: History of science is a discipline with its methods and tools.

Comment: I disagree with the premise: we often do. See for example: Art History, History of Science. Also, often in subjects themselves we study their history. For example: Bio 101 courses usually cover Watson + Crick, the development of the "central dogma" etc.

Answer (score 2):

A physicist may be better qualified to explain the conceptual structures of various theories and how they are related, but that is not history, it's analysis.

The physicist is just about the last person I would ask to explain the influence of physics outside of physics, or even within physics, really.  Things happen, in physics as elsewhere, for all sorts of weird reasons.  Jealousy within  a lab could have profound impact on what happens the lab, for example. Unless I wanted a profoundly biased opinion.  Surely you do not think that science is somehow isolated from the rest of the world. Power is everywhere the same - the obvious example is nuclear physics: no WW2, no atom bomb, at least not for a while.  History is in its way just as scientific as physics; the only difference is historians don't get to conduct experiments, and contrary to popular opinion, history never repeats itself, so no replicability.  But good historians are just as conscientious and as intellectually disciined as physicists.

Take the example of the Chicago Assyrian Dictionary.  It only took about 70 years to produce.

Personally I think it's actually harder to be a good historian than to be a good physicist.  The physicist must learn lots of arcane math, among other things.  The historian may have to learn a half dozen dead languages some of which have relatively little surviving evidence.  Doing that kind of history is *incredibly* complex.  That's why in some fields of history nobody makes a mark until well into middle age.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the question, because I have some experience with this topic.  I worked as a History and Social Sciences Instructor for over ten years and so often, I was asked by my students, "Why do we need to study History?", "What is the point of studying a subject, such as History?

There are many answers to this question, though I will be happy to provide the readers with AN answer....(and NOT THE answer):

One studies History as a unique and distinct subject in order to better understand the process of TIME, more specifically, Chronological time. When examining its most basic and purposeful role, History is a subject which, (if taught correctly), aims to introduce, familiarize and even train students, to think about the significance of an event(s) within the context of chronological time.  One should not confuse the studying of chronological time with juvenile exercises in memorization-(i.e. dates and places).  The teaching of chronological time, is a lengthy (and not so simple) process, which necessitates the juxtaposition of an event and its appropriate place within historical time.

There are the expected critics and naysayers who say that the chronological approach is antiquated.  Sadly, the field of History, in recent times, is becoming increasingly preoccupied with Social Activist commentaries-(and curricula!).  It may be that the chronological approach is "old fashioned" and that it is largely (and proudly) detached from Social Activism. However, I have learned, over the years, that the PRIMARY role of the History Instructor is to design a curriculum and a set of lessons which aims to introduce students to the rudiments of chronological reasoning and its DIRECT relationship with an event(s) in historical time.  The discipline of History should NEVER be used as a righteous political weapon, nor should it ever serve as a Soapbox/Podium for exclaiming righteous grievances.  The field of History MUST always strive towards teaching students to broaden their awareness of (and even appreciate), the complexities of historical time.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly because the history of a subject is not a part - a sub-field - of the subject itself. The history of physics, which would include the speculations of the Babylonians, Egyptians and Ancient Greeks, is no part of what we recognise as physics. The history of physics is dead physics. If a physicist were interested in the history of physics, this would not be an inquiry within physics - but an external inquiry. Nor would a physicist as such have the necessary knowledge to conduct the inquiry. How many physicists can interpret cuneiform?

One exception to the rule is philosophy. The history of philosophy is a part of philosophy because of the perennial nature of many philosophical problems. The history of philosophy is a living past. We do not do philosophy as Locke did it in the 17th century but his account of personal identity - to take just one topic - with its emphasis on the psychological and not merely the physical continuity of the subject (the person) is still suggestive to many present-day philosophers even if many others totally reject it.